# how to move sass to laravel

Tags: css, laravel, sass

#ask

Hello I want to ask,

Now I'm working on a college project, using laravel, when I enter the Blade Templating stage in Laravel ... I'm having trouble trying to move the .sass file to my Laravel project.

because previously when making the initial appearance of the website that I created, I used sass.

the question is, how do you get the .sass file to run in laravel?

#first-effort
previously I've searched on google and got the same question on stackoverflow... he suggested to install npm "npm install", then move all my css and sass files to resources/assets/sass after that run the command "npm run dev"  , then it says all files will go to the app.css file

but after I try to run it, the result is still the same.

#my sass photo
https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNmP1.jpg

#Project display now when run
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMdpw.jpg (there is some styling because I made some styling in main.css, but the rest is in the sass file, so it looks messy like that)

#My Project display "should" (this is still running using html css on local)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/svSE4.jpg

Please help

Comment: Take a look at the webpack.mix.js file. in that file you can make the sass compile to a  css file in the public css folder. (when using `npm run dev`). something like `mix.sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')`

Comment: BTW don't add images of code to your question, add the code in your question.